# Philippine passport validity when traveling to the US

Tags: usa, passports

I have a valid Philippine passport that will expire on July 5, 2018. Will I have issues traveling to the US on a B1 Visa by January 2018? (technically it is still 7 months right?). I will stay there for 3 months.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [latest version of the "six-month-club update"](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2017-Jan/Six-Month%20Club%20Update%2012-5-16.pdf), the Philippines is among the countries whose nationals may enter the US as long as the passport is valid until the day of departure.  If you arrive after January 6th, you will probably be given less than six months admission, because you will be admitted until your passport's expiration date.  As long as you leave before then, you should be fine.

Also see the CBP's page on [Technical Requirements for Passports (machine readable)](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/905/~/technical-requirements-for-passports-%28machine-readable%29).